# Redirecting outbound traffic to specific IP to localhost

Tags: iptables

I'm mocking a service, which would in actuality run on 10.1.10.1, and in so doing am trying to redirect the traffic bound for 10.1.10.1 to 127.0.0.1.  To create my rule, I'm running

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.1.10.1 --dport 443 -j DNAT \
  --to-destination 127.0.0.1:43000
```

It doesn't report an error, but it also doesn't appear to add it; when I run iptables -L, I don't see it anywhere. Is there a way I can see what might have gone wrong? Or, is this not the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iptables -L doesn't list NAT rules. To list NAT rules, you have to run

```
iptables -t nat -L
```

Similarly, for any NAT based operations (adding a rule, a chain, deleting, listing, etc), you have to specify the -t option.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
 sudo iptables -t nat -nvL
```

One question, were you able to routing https/443 on your localhost? I have exact the same same requirement, but I am not able to route it.